# Losing window values when replacing entire html in ajax callback (FF, IE)

Tags: javascript, html, cross-browser

i have a page A, using this ajax submit function:

```
$('#bo').submit(function( event ) {

             $.ajax({
                url : "./home.html",
                cache : false,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType : "html",
            }).done(function(data) {

                    window['user'] = $('#user').val();
                    window['pass'] = $('#pass').val();

                   var  doc = document.open("text/html");
                    doc.write(data.toString());
                    doc.close();


                });


            return false;
        });
```

Im trying to set some window attributes because, when i replace the html (page B) i still can use those attributes in some functions.. Its working fine on Chrome.. but isnt on IE/FF

Is there a workaround? Or maybe another way to get the request header when page b is loaded so i dont need to replace the html to 'save' the window attrs? Or something like this?

Comment: If those attributes are obtained from the DOM that you are replacing, is it possible that on replacing the whole page they are also removed. Maybe you should make a copy of the values or clone them.

Comment: try using `document.body.innerHTML = data;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing `event.preventDefault()`, so you are submitting to a new page, and not making an AJAX call.

Comment: Should `return false;` do the same?

Comment: No, you want to stop the default action of the submit button, which is to submit the form. You can also use a regular button and use a click event instead of submit.